# Make external files dependent on a project in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have some external files in my project that are frequently changed. However, they are not considered to be source files by CMake, so if I change one of the external files, the project is not rebuilt. I do have this however

```
set(EXTERNAL file1 file2)
add_executable(${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} ${EXTERNAL})
```

If I change the actual sources or headers, Visual Studio recognizes the change and rebuilds the project. It doesn't do this for the external files though. How would I force CMake to check for changes in the external files and rebuild them? I was thinking about adding the external files as a custom target and adding that as a dependency to the actual project, but I don't know how well that would work.

Comment: What type of files are the external files?

Comment: Is it one of the extension defined in `CMAKE_CXX_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS` to be ignored by CMake itself (as not a source file):  `inl;h;hpp;HPP;H;o;O;obj;OBJ;def;DEF;rc;RC`? Otherwise I would have expected CMake to throw an error/warning about those external files.